# Can I destructure a self param?

Tags: rust

I'd like `foo1` and `foo2` to behave analogously, however the compiler doesn't accept `foo2`. Is there anyway to destructure the self param the way that one can destructure other params? I don't see a clear answer in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#-bindings).

```
struct Foo {
    x: usize,
    y: usize
}
impl Foo {
    fn foo1(f @ Foo { x , ..}: &Foo) -> usize{ f.y + x}
    fn foo2(&self @ Foo { x , ..}) -> usize { self.y + x }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any semantic reason you couldn't but it may just not be supported by the grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot destructure from `self` in the function parameters.

If you look at the grammar for [functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/functions.html) in the Rust Reference (which is referenced to by [associated items](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html)), the portions about `self` are handled uniquely (trimmed):

```
Function :
   FunctionQualifiers fn IDENTIFIER GenericParams?
      ( FunctionParameters? )
      FunctionReturnType? WhereClause?
      ( BlockExpression | ; )

...

FunctionParameters :
      SelfParam ,?
   | (SelfParam ,)? FunctionParam (, FunctionParam)* ,?

SelfParam :
   OuterAttribute* ( ShorthandSelf | TypedSelf )

ShorthandSelf :
   (& | & Lifetime)? mut? self

TypedSelf :
   mut? self : Type

...
```

There is no consideration for other bindings via `@` when using `self`. It would need to be a [identifier pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#identifier-patterns) or use similar grammar for that to work.

You *can* destructure from a `&Self` type, but since you still wouldn't be able to call the binding `self` it would be disqualified as a *method receiver* so that doesn't change anything compared to your `foo1()` version. If you want it to operate as a method while destructuring some fields, you'll need to do it in two steps shown in [@drewtato's answer](/a/76957772/2189130).

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like this is possible, but you can always destructure it in the function body.

```rs
fn foo2(&self) -> usize {
    let Foo { x, .. } = self;
    self.y + x
}
```